# MySQL stored login procedure [return tables]

Tags: c#, mysql, database, routines

I'm trying to create a simple login for an ASP.net web application where I use MySQL as database and ODBC as a connector. Now I would like to prevent SQL injections by calling MySQL routines instead of application-side SQL.

Traditionally, I can run an SQL statement and recieve a table result, which I can store in a data class. This way, I have always comfortable access to e.g. the users properties like roles etc. without querying the database again.
Now with mysql procedures or functions, it seems I can only return simple values like string, int or bit instead of full tables.
So when I like to have the full table, do I have to run 2 queries? One as a stored function that returns e.g. the user id if the login was successful, another one for the users information? Or are functions capable of returning full tables?

Comment: Unlike other DBMS, MySQL functions cannot return a result set (that can be used like a table). But I believe (not sure!) that MySQL at least supports ref cursors, which can also be used to return a result from a procedure.

Comment: Moving your logic to the database not only does not prevent SQL injection, but also couples your application to the database in a difficult to reverse way. Use the established (Traditional) `SqlCommand` or equivalent, validate your input, keep your logic in C#, versioned and clean, decoupled from the rest of the application using a data access layer, repository pattern, or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to write Table-Valued Stored procedure in MySQL Server. MySQL Stored Function returns single values only.

However, if the situation demands a Function to return a set of Data, you have only two choices:

- You may create a string using some separators with your result set and return it to the caller.
- Another good alternative is to use Temporary Table.

[More details here](http://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/mysql-stored-function-that-returns-table/).

And please refer the [mysql doc too](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html).

Answer (score 1):

First, I completely agree with your new approach.  It's a very good idea to keep SQL code out of your application.

I guess that would depend on your ODBC driver.  I know from experience you can use the [MySQL Connector for .Net](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net.html).  You can definitely get a dataset from a stored procedure with it.